# Gulp: Error - "Task function must be specified"

Tags: npm, gulp

When I try to run the gulp command:

```
gulp dist --Layout="vertical-dark-menu-template" --LayoutName="vertical-dark-menu-template" --ThemeName="vertical-dark-menu-template" --TextDirection="LTR"
```

I get an error, one of which is reoccurring.

I've already tried reinstalling gulp and npm.

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
// Require the modules.
var gulp             = require('gulp');
var gutil            = require('gulp-util');
var gulpSequence     = require('gulp-sequence');
var gulpRequireTasks = require('gulp-require-tasks');
var minimist         = require('minimist');
var config            = require('./config.json');

var options          = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));

// Global Variables
global.myLayout        = options.Layout;
global.myLayoutName    = options.LayoutName;
global.myThemeName     = options.ThemeName;
global.config           = config;

global.dashboardRename = '';
global.rtl             = '';
global.dist            = "false";

if( options.dist !== undefined ){
    dist = options.dist;
}
if (options.TextDirection !== undefined){
    global.myTextDirection = options.TextDirection.toLowerCase();
    if (myTextDirection == 'rtl')
        rtl = '-rtl';
}
else{
    global.myTextDirection = '';
}

gutil.log(gutil.colors.green('Starting Gulp!!'));

// Exclude template specific files
if (myLayout == 'vertical-modern-menu-template') {
    dashboardRename = config.vertical_modern_menu_template.dashboardRename;
    pugSrc         = config.vertical_modern_menu_template.pugSrc;
} else if (myLayout == 'vertical-menu-nav-dark-template') {
    dashboardRename = config.vertical_menu_nav_dark_template.dashboardRename;
    pugSrc         = config.vertical_menu_nav_dark_template.pugSrc;
} else if (myLayout == 'vertical-gradient-menu-template') {
    dashboardRename = config.vertical_gradient_menu_template.dashboardRename;
    pugSrc         = config.vertical_gradient_menu_template.pugSrc;
} else if (myLayout == 'vertical-dark-menu-template') {
    dashboardRename = config.vertical_dark_menu_template.dashboardRename;
    pugSrc         = config.vertical_dark_menu_template.pugSrc;
} else if (myLayout == 'horizontal-menu-template') {
    dashboardRename = config.horizontal_menu_template.dashboardRename;
    pugSrc         = config.horizontal_menu_template.pugSrc;
} 

// Invoke the module with options.
gulpRequireTasks({

    // Specify path to your tasks directory.
    path: process.cwd() + '/gulp-tasks' // This is default!

    // Additionally pass any options to it from the table below.
    // ...
    // path - './gulp-tasks'    Path to directory from which to load your tasks modules
    // separator -  :   Task name separator, your tasks would be named, e.g. foo:bar:baz for ./tasks/foo/bar/baz.js
    // arguments -  []  Additional arguments to pass to your task function
    // passGulp - true  Whether to pass Gulp instance as a first argument to your task function
    // passCallback -   true    Whether to pass task callback function as a last argument to your task function
    // gulp - require('gulp')   You could pass your existing Gulp instance if you have one, or it will be required automatically

});

// Clean Task.
gulp.task('dist-clean', ['clean:css', 'clean:js']);

// Monitor changes for both pug and sass files.
gulp.task('monitor', gulpSequence(['sass:watch']));

// JS Distribution Task.
gulp.task('dist-js', gulpSequence('clean:js', 'copy:js', 'uglify:min', 'notify:js'));

// SASS Compile Task.
gulp.task('sass-compile', function(callback) {
    gulpSequence('file-write:sass-file', 'file-write:sass-page-variable-file', ['sass:main', 'sass:theme', 'sass:layouts', 'sass:pages', 'sass:custom'], 'autoprefixer:css', 'csscomb:css', 'cssmin:css')(callback)
 });

// CSS Distribution Task.
gulp.task('dist-css', gulpSequence('sass-compile', 'notify:css'));

// Full Distribution Task.
gulp.task('dist', ['dist-css', 'dist-js']);

// Default Task.
gulp.task('default', ['dist']);

gulp.task('replacement', gulpSequence('replacement:css', 'replacement:js'));
```

I expect the command to run successfully to generate JS and CSS files but instead an error is thrown. These specific JS and CSS files that I am attempting to generate allow a template that I am using to function properly. The specific error message that I keep on receiving when I run the designated command is:

```
assert.js:339

    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\chann\Documents\GitHub\integratedesports.com\materialize-admin-template\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\chann\Documents\GitHub\integratedesports.com\materialize-admin-template\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chann\Documents\GitHub\integratedesports.com\materialize-admin-template\gulpfile.js:71:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

Comment: Are you using gulp4 (gulp -v)?  If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554991/everytime-i-get-an-assertion-error-while-running-gulp-in-command-line/56555201#56555201

Comment: @Mark CLI version: 2.2.0 and Local version: 4.0.2